# MS sql stored procedure aggregate data based on some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL table with three fields  Id, Player , ColorNumber.  The Id is not primary key and can be repeated . Here is the table  as follows:

[image]

I want to use this to create a Captains table, for example . But the captain should be selected on maximum occurences of a player for a given Id.

eg. For 123 , Mike occurs most so ,the captain should be Mike.
For 345 , no clear majority , so leave captain field blank
For 567 , it will be Schuyler , even though space and Schuyler have same counts.
For 898 it is Mary. Do note that Mike also occurs in the 898 key.

Here is my output.

[image]

So far , I wrote :

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as counts,[Class ID],Player
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Players]
    GROUP BY [Class ID],Player
```

which gave me a result as :

[image]

I am guessing a stored procedure would be the best way to write this and get the new table opposed to a new direct query . Since I need to handle the case where if there are equally occurring names then the captain will be blank. However , I am fairly new to stored procedures and am not sure how to go about it and re-use the information from the query above to do this and handle the cases. I guess there is  a CASE .. WHEN operation i looked at in procedures but I am unsure how I can use that.

Please do suggest if you have another alternative as opposed to procedure . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the "mode" in statistics.  You can easily do this using window function:

```
SELECT [Class ID],
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN PLAYER END), MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN PLAYER END)
               ) as captain
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as counts, [Class ID], Player,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Class ID] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [Test].[dbo].[Players] p
      GROUP BY [Class ID], Player
     ) p
GROUP BY [Class ID];
```

Note:  The `COALESCE()` is needed because you have a lot of blank values.  I suspect that you don't want them for the captain.

EDIT:

If you want none when there are ties:

```
SELECT [Class ID],
       (CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND cnt = 1 AND player IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
             THEN PLAYER
             WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 AND cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN NULL
             WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 AND cnt = 1
             THEN PLAYER
          END) as captain
FROM (SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Class ID], seqnum) as cnt
      FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as counts, [Class ID], Player,
                   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Class ID] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
            FROM [Test].[dbo].[Players] p
            GROUP BY [Class ID], Player
           ) p
     ) p
GROUP BY [Class ID];
```

Comment: Hi Gordon , that's a terrific answer . Thank you.

Comment: But the output i get is 123-> Mike , 345->Randy , 567-> <Blank> , 898->Mary 

123 and 898 are correct. For 345 , all players have equal counts so I want to leave captain as blank. For 567, Schuyler has 2 , space has 2. Both are equal but I want Schuyler as captain. As you can see my output . This seems like pro-level SQL! Briliant but still a wee bit away.

Comment: SELECT [Class ID],
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 and PLAYER not in ('',' ') THEN PLAYER END), MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN PLAYER END)
               ) as captain
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as counts, [Class ID], Player,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Class ID] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [Test].[dbo].[Players] p
      GROUP BY [Class ID], Player
     ) p
GROUP BY [Class ID];

This gets me as far except for inputting blank if there are no clear maximum counts.  @Gordon Linoff